# webpart.ts dropdownlist fetch from list but the list repeats itself

Tags: spfx-custom-property-pane

I am creating a webpart that has a property panel that loads the list of Title into the dropdownlist

1. On Click Edit Webpart, the Title DropDown List is Empty
2. Second Click , the Title Dropdown List shows the Options
3. If I click the Add Button, the Title Dropdown List shows empty
4. If I click the Edit Webpart the Title Dropdown list grows from 4 to 8 ....

Is there a way I can control the behaviour like

- if finish rendering, reset the this.options array to empty
- Upon re-rendering, always reset this.options array to empty then fetch list from sharepoint list
- To which function /method in webpart.ts I can render the this.getList() to fetch list from sharepoint?

webpart.ts

```
export default class MylinkWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<
  IMylinkWebPartProps
> {
  private options = [];
  private linksset = new Set();

  private handleClick() {
    this.linksset.add(this.properties.linkName);
    let array = [];
    this.linksset.forEach(v => array.push(v));
    this.properties.data = [...array];

    //refresh main page to show links
    this.onDispose();
    this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
    this.render();
  }

  private getList() {
    this.options.length = 0;
    const opt: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    };
    this.context.spHttpClient
      .get(
        this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
          "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylink')/items",
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        opt
      )
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        response.json().then((json: any) => {
          for (var x = 0; x < json.value.length; x++) {
            this.options.push({
              key: json.value[x].Title,
              text: json.value[x].Title
            });
          }
          console.log("options=", this.options);
        });
      });
  }

  public render(): void {
    this.getList();
    console.log(this.options);
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMylinkProps> = React.createElement(
      Mylink,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        pagecontext: this.context.pageContext,
        SPHttpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
        linkName: this.properties.linkName,
        add: this.properties.add,
        data: this.properties.data,
        fontsize: this.properties.fontsize
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse("1.0");
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: ""
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: "Select Links to Add",
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneDropdown("linkName", {
                  label: "Title",

                  options: this.options
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField("URL", {
                  label: "URL"
                }),
                PropertyPaneButton("add", {
                  text: "Add Link",
                  buttonType: PropertyPaneButtonType.Primary,
                  onClick: this.handleClick.bind(this)
                }),
                PropertyPaneSlider("fontsize", {
                  label: "Font Size",
                  min: 10,
                  max: 32,
                  value: 12,
                  showValue: true,
                  step: 1
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    //this.options.length = 0;
  }
}
```

[image: The problem]